# Usage of can and could

Tags: modal-verbs

> He goes to London every month so that he **can** see his ailing father.

Can we use **could**  in the above sentence instead of **can**?

Some people are saying we can't use "could" here, as could is used in past forms and  the sentence is in present tense form (goes to london every week is present tense).

But I know "could" is not just used in Past tense sentences. It is used in both past tense and hypothetical forms. Past tense form of "could"  is clearly impossible here as sentence is in present tense. So, can we use "could" in hypothetical sense or to express possibility, like "He goes to London every week so that he **could** see his father, if he was permitted into hospital"?

Comment: Do you mean "I know _could_ is used in past tense and hypothetical forms"? _Can_ can't be past tense. You can say _If he was permitted to go into the hospital, he could visit his father_.

Comment: No I didn't mean it. I edited the question, please read it.  I learnt could can be used in 1)Past forms 2) Hypothetical forms.  Can we use "could" instead of "can"  in the given sentence, to make it hypothetical??? Or    it's not possible to use "could" , because it gives past tense form to the sentence, which is incorrect, as independent clause is in present tense.

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda  No, just putting in "could" doesn't make it a hypothetical, so the form as shown isn't right. Here's a hypothetical: `He would go to London every week so that he could see his father, if he was permitted to enter the hospital."

Comment: You   could use the non-past _could_ of possiblility in a similar sentence thus; _When he goes to London, he **could** see his father_ (with stress on "could") means "it would be possible for him to see his father", with an implication that the speaker thinks it unlikely that he will do so.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Then Is "He goes to London every month so that he could see his ailing father"  wrong?? or is there any possible meaning for it???

Comment: @ColinFine Then Is "He goes to London every month so that he could see his ailing father" wrong?? or is there any possible meaning for it???

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda That would be said "...to see his ailing father."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty ThankYou so much, I know "... to see his ailing father" is correct. But my doubt is , Is " .... so that he could see his ailing father" wrong??

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda I agree with Colin Fine. What would it mean? Nothing occurs to me, so I would take it as incorrect.

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda: no. If I read that, when I got to _could_, I would go "What? This doesn't make any sense". I would assume that it had originally said "He went to London every month" and the first verb had been edited but the second left.